# jQuery each() - How does it work really internally?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've consulted the jQuery source on this, but I must admit it's probably beyond my understanding - or I'm looking in the wrong place. 
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js

Around line 222 there is a function that looks recursive, and then again around line 566 there is another one declared in .extend() namespace.

I'm just curious - how exactly does this work? For example, when I call:

```
$('.item').each(function(){
    // Do Something
});
```

How does it know to cycle through the array of DOM elements, when to stop, how does it apply the function? It cant just do

```
$('.item').doThis()
```

because doThis() might not be a member of that object.

Please enlighten me :) thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L596, that's where the magic happens... no recursion anywhere. I admit the `for` loop looks a bit awkward, but it's nothing fancy.

Comment: Ever tried reading a source code of jQuery? that would be better. Besides, 90% of people using jQuery at professional level have no idea how it works. ;)

Comment: The real function is on line 566.

Comment: @Fratyr See the first sentence of the question...

Comment: I wonder why questions like this are termed as not constructive..Its pretty handy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not recursive. The function on [line 222](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L222) is the one on jQuery's prototype (`$.fn`), while the function it calls is `jQuery.each` - a static property which is defined in [line 566](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L566). Notice how [`extend`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L272) works: If no object to extend is given, it uses `this`. It is both applied on `jQuery` and `jQuery.fn` in different sections of the code.

> so how exactly does this work?

`$obj.each(callback)` is calling the `$.fn.each` method, which applies `$.each` on the jQuery instance (the DOM wrapper) itself: [line 223](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L223).

Now, in `$.each`, there are four cases: With or without supplied `args` array, and on an array-like structure or on other objects. You didn't pass additional args, and jQuery instances have a `length` property and have the DOM elements in numeric indices, so the loop in [line 596](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L596) will be executed. So your call is equivalent to

```
for (var i=0, len=$obj.length; i<len; i++)
    if ( callback.call($obj[i], i, $obj[i]) === false ) break;
```

Comment: Thanks - it was especially helpful that you cleared up which function was which and exactly what the extend() method was doing. It's a shame this thread got closed - I feel like more jQuery users could do with understanding the innards. The one thing that still sort of puzzles me is how the iteration happens - for example, when I provide an array of three items, how does that array get brought into the each function if it's not really an argument?

Comment: It is the first argument of `$.each` - `obj`. If you use `$.fn.each`, the array-like jQuery instance itself (`this`) is passed.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, this

```
$('selector').each(func);
```

is the equivalent of doing this:

```
func = ...;
$selector = $('selector');
for (var i = 0; i < $selector.length; i++) {
    if (func.call($selector[i], i, $selector[i]) === false) {
        break;
    }
}
```

The object returned by a $ selection is actually an array of DOM elements with a whole bunch of extra methods attached to it, so you basically can work with it just like you would an Array.  Hope that clears things up!

Comment: Strictly speaking it's equivalent to `func.call($selector[i], i, $selector[i]);`.

Comment: Thanks for that Felix, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Each query you do in jQuery is stored as an Array like object, meaning you can access the list of DOM elements your query has found by doing this:

```
$('.item')[0] //The first item found by your query
```

Internally, $().each uses $.each, which is a way of iterating through your collection, calling the function you've passed as the argument, and using 'Function.apply' to set 'this' to be the current object being iterated through.

Answer (score 0):

Check out lines 566 to 605 in [the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js)

It is iterative and fairly straightforward.